# UIImageView setImage crashes on background thread since Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, background-process

Since Xcode 10 on iOS, the following is crashing with:
`[Animation] +[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:] being called from a background thread. Performing any operation from a background thread on UIView or a subclass is not supported and may result in unexpected and insidious behavior. trace=...`

when launched from background thread.

```
+(UIImage *)circularImage:(UIImage *)image withDiameter:(NSUInteger)diameter
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, diameter, diameter);
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [imageView setImage:image]; <--- crashing here
...
}
```

Is that normal that I can't assign a simple UIImage to an UIImageView in a background thread ?

Comment: Don't update UI in a background thread always use **dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});**

Comment: Normal and crucial. Your code was always wrong; now you're busted. You might say: but this UIImageView is not in the interface! That doesn't matter. UIKit is _not thread-safe_.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can access the UI elements only from the main thread. You can't access it from other threads. That's why the app is crashing. Use the code below.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //update your UI stuff here.
});
```

You could do the same with Swift as below.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { // your UI stuff here }
```

Thanks to @lenooh for pointing it out.

Comment: for Swift, that would be: `DispatchQueue.main.async { // your UI stuff here }`